# IONIC 2 - Component Tab Menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

New to Ionic 2 and Angular 2.
Trying to simply add a tab menu (component) to some of my pages.

menu.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

menu.component.html

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-text" [color]="isAndroid ? 'royal' : 'primary'">
      <ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="leaf" tabTitle="Life" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="flame" tabTitle="Fire" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
      <ion-tab tabIcon="magnet" tabTitle="Force" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
```

Then I want to add it to this page :

home.ts

```js
import { MenuComponent } from "../../app/Componets/Menu/menu.component";
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController

  ) {

  }

  navigation: string = "Apps";

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }
```

}

home.html

```html
//html....
<ion-content padding>
<menu></menu>

</ion-content>
```

Can anyone advise what I have missed? as the menu does not display

Answer (score 1):

Each [root] need refer a page ( import all that pages in your home ), like this:

```
<ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab tabIcon="leaf" tabTitle="Life" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab tabIcon="flame" tabTitle="Fire" [root]="tab3"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab tabIcon="magnet" tabTitle="Force" [root]="tab4"></ion-tab>
      </ion-tabs>`
```

In the .ts link the root's to the pages:

```
export class Home{

tab1Root = tab1;
tab2Root = tab2;
tab3Root = tab3;
tab4Root = tab4;


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
}
```

See the components document in Ionic Docs:
    https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs
    https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/

Answer (score 0):

In your `menu.component.ts` you haven't imported `rootPage`, although in `menu.component.html` you specify it as the root of all your tabs, for example in your code you have:

```html
<ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
```

See [this example implementation](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-starter-super/blob/master/src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts) from the ionic team.